# TikZ: Node placement best practices in an already cramped figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

How can I place more nodes in an already cramped figure?  Here is intended outcome:

[image]

Here is my current figure:

[image]

I am looking to add the velocity vector notation and the time notations `(t_f < t_m)` both greater and less than.

How can I add the remaining nodes in an already crowded figure?

If you need to see the code, I can post it as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc, arrows, decorations.markings, backgrounds}
\tikzset{
  invclip/.style={
    clip,
    insert path={
        (-520pt, -520pt) rectangle (520pt, 520pt)
      }
    }
  }
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.75,
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
      shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
    dot/.default =,
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 2.5pt, dot = {#1}},
    small dot/.default =,
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 5pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.default =,
    line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45
    ]
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{0.2768}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\etilde}{0.6789}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1.36}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a * sqrt(1 - \e^2)} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\btilde}{\a * sqrt(1 - (\etilde)^2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ctilde}{sqrt(\a^2 - (\btilde)^2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{88.23}

  \draw[dashed, rotate = \angle] (-\a + \ctilde, 0) -- (\a + \ctilde, 0);
  \draw[dashed] (-\a - \c, 0) -- (\a - \c, 0);

  \node[font = \scriptsize, fill = orange, big dot = {below: \(F\)}] (F)
  at (0, 0) {};
  \node[font = \scriptsize, fill = white, big dot = {below: \(F^*\)}] (FS)
  at (-2 * \c cm, 0) {};

  \path[name path global = ecc2768] (-\c, 0) ellipse[x radius = \a cm,
  y radius = \b cm];

  \draw[red, name path = r2] (0, 0) circle[radius = 1.523679cm];
  \draw[blue, name path = r1] (0, 0) circle[radius = 1cm];
  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc2768 and r1}] (F) -- (intersection-1)
  node[fill, big dot = {right: \(P_1\)}] (P1) {};
  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc2768 and r2}] (F) -- (intersection-1)
  node[fill, big dot = {above left: \(P_2\)}] (P2) {};
  \draw[draw = none] (P1) -- (F) node[font = \scriptsize, pos = .5,
  fill = white, inner sep = 0cm] {\(r_1\)};
  \draw[draw = none] (P2) -- (F) node[font = \scriptsize, pos = .5,
  fill = white, inner sep = 0cm] {\(r_2\)};
  \draw (P1) -- (P2) node[font = \scriptsize, fill = white, inner sep = 0cm,
  pos = .5] {\(c\)};

  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
          mark = at position 0.7 with {\arrow{latex reversed}}
        }]
        \path[invclip] (0, 0) -- ($(0,0)!100cm!(P1)$) -- (0cm, 100cm) -- 
        ($(0,0)!100cm!(P2)$) -- (0, 0);

        \draw[name path global = ecc2768, postaction = decorate] (-\c, 0)
        ellipse [x radius = \a cm, y radius = \b cm];
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

  \draw let
    \p0 = (F),
    \p1 = (P1),
    \p2 = (P2),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
    \n3 = {.35cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (F) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
  node[font = \scriptsize, fill = white, inner sep = 0cm] at
  ([shift = (F)] \n4:.5cm) {\pgfmathparse{\n2 - \n1}%
    $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}^{\circ}$
  };

  \path[name path = aux1] (P1) circle[radius = 1bp];

  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc2768 and aux1}, latex-]
  ($(intersection-2)!.75cm!(intersection-1)$) -- (P1);

  \path[name path = aux2] (P2) circle[radius = 1bp];

  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc2768 and aux2}, -latex]
  (P2) -- ($(intersection-1)!.75cm!(intersection-2)$);

  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
          mark = at position 0.5 with {\arrow{latex reversed}}
        }]
        \path[name path global = ecc6789unrotated] (\ctilde, 0) ellipse    
        (\a cm and \btilde cm);
        \path[invclip] (0, 0) -- ($(0,0)!100cm!(P1)$) -- (0cm, 100cm) -- 
        ($(0,0)!100cm!(P2)$) -- (0, 0);

        \draw [name intersections = {of = r1 and ecc6789unrotated},
        postaction = decorate] (intersection-2) let
          \p0 = (F),
          \p1 = (P1),
          \p2 = (intersection-2),
          \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
          \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
          \n3 = {\n1 - \n2}
        in \pgfextra{\xdef\myangle{\n3}} [rotate = \n3,
        name path global = ecc6789rotated] (\ctilde, 0) ellipse
        [x radius = \a cm, y radius = \btilde cm];
        % \node at (0,3) {The angle of rotation is: \pgfmathparse{\myangle}
        % $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}^\circ$};
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

  \begin{scope}[rotate around = {\myangle: (0, 0)}]
    \node[font = \scriptsize, fill = white, big dot = {left: \(\tilde{F}^*\)}]
    (FST) at (2 * \ctilde cm, 0) {};
  \end{scope}

  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc6789rotated and aux1}, -latex] (P1) --
  ($(intersection-2)!.75cm!(intersection-1)$);
  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc6789rotated and aux2}, -latex] (P2) --
  ($(intersection-1)!.75cm!(intersection-2)$);

  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    % To prevent the clipping path from making our picture larger
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
          mark = at position 0.2 with {\arrow{latex}},
        }]
        \path[clip] (0, 0) -- ($(0,0)!100cm!(P1)$) -- (0cm, 100cm) -- 
        ($(0,0)!100cm!(P2)$) -- (0, 0);

        \draw [orange, postaction = decorate] (-\c, 0) ellipse
        [x radius = \a cm, y radius = \b cm];
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    % To prevent the clipping path from making our picture larger
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
          mark = at position 0 with {\arrow{latex}},
        }]
        \path[clip] (0, 0) -- ($(0,0)!100cm!(P1)$) -- (0cm, 100cm) -- 
        ($(0,0)!100cm!(P2)$) -- (0, 0);

        \draw [name intersections = {of = r1 and ecc6789unrotated},
        postaction = decorate, PineGreen] (intersection-2) 
        let
          \p0 = (F),
          \p1 = (P1),
          \p2 = (intersection-2),
          \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
          \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
          \n3 = {\n1 - \n2}
        in \pgfextra{\xdef\myangle{\n3}} [rotate = \n3,
        name path global = ecc6789rotated] (\ctilde, 0) ellipse
        [x radius = \a cm, y radius = \btilde cm];
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it would be good to have the code.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina added

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes updated.

Comment: Is this still an active question? What have you tried already? If you want to mark certain points inside a cramped figure you could position the text outside of all circles/ellipses and draw a fine line from there to the point while potentially over-drawing un-important parts of the circles.

Comment: I was going to update my answer to reflect some more modern syntax from the `stackengine` package (`\stackinset` rather than `\bottominset`) and realized that your MWE and my answer now produce a vertically inverted tikz image.  I'm guessing you were the victim of a tikz package upgrade, but do you know what parameter to tweak so as to recreate your original figure?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it is the definition of atan2.  I think if you switch the xs and ys it should work.  Let me know if it does.

Comment: Thanks!  That took care of 95% of it... there is still a slight vertical shift of my inset labels, but I don't know if that is a `tikz` evolution or a `stackengine` evolution.  I can adjust for that.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the one think that bothers me is I have 250-500 images using the wrong atan2 definition now.

Comment: Ouch!  I don't envy you that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe not what you are looking for, but I used `stackengine`'s `\stackinset` macro to overlay what you had done with the remaining labels.  All the "action" is at the bottom of my MWE, and falls outside of the `tikz` environment.

UPDATED to reflect more modern syntax of `stackengine` package, using `\stackinset` rather than the deprecated `\bottominset` macro. (Also, the `tikz` atan2 macro changed syntax)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc, arrows, decorations.markings, backgrounds}
\tikzset{
  invclip/.style={
    clip,
    insert path={
        (-520pt, -520pt) rectangle (520pt, 520pt)
      }
    }
  }
\usepackage{stackengine}
  \begin{document}
\newsavebox{\mypic}
\sbox{\mypic}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.75,
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
      shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
    dot/.default =,
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 2.5pt, dot = {#1}},
    small dot/.default =,
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 5pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.default =,
    line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45
    ]
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{0.2768}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\etilde}{0.6789}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1.36}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a * sqrt(1 - \e^2)} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\btilde}{\a * sqrt(1 - (\etilde)^2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ctilde}{sqrt(\a^2 - (\btilde)^2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{88.23}

  \draw[dashed, rotate = \angle] (-\a + \ctilde, 0) -- (\a + \ctilde, 0);
  \draw[dashed] (-\a - \c, 0) -- (\a - \c, 0);

  \node[font = \scriptsize, fill = orange, big dot = {below: \(F\)}] (F)
  at (0, 0) {};
  \node[font = \scriptsize, fill = white, big dot = {below: \(F^*\)}] (FS)
  at (-2 * \c cm, 0) {};

  \path[name path global = ecc2768] (-\c, 0) ellipse[x radius = \a cm,
  y radius = \b cm];

  \draw[red, name path = r2] (0, 0) circle[radius = 1.523679cm];
  \draw[blue, name path = r1] (0, 0) circle[radius = 1cm];
  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc2768 and r1}] (F) -- (intersection-1)
  node[fill, big dot = {right: \(P_1\)}] (P1) {};
  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc2768 and r2}] (F) -- (intersection-1)
  node[fill, big dot = {above left: \(P_2\)}] (P2) {};
  \draw[draw = none] (P1) -- (F) node[font = \scriptsize, pos = .5,
  fill = white, inner sep = 0cm] {\(r_1\)};
  \draw[draw = none] (P2) -- (F) node[font = \scriptsize, pos = .5,
  fill = white, inner sep = 0cm] {\(r_2\)};
  \draw (P1) -- (P2) node[font = \scriptsize, fill = white, inner sep = 0cm,
  pos = .5] {\(c\)};

  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
          mark = at position 0.7 with {\arrow{latex reversed}}
        }]
        \path[invclip] (0, 0) -- ($(0,0)!100cm!(P1)$) -- (0cm, 100cm) -- 
        ($(0,0)!100cm!(P2)$) -- (0, 0);

        \draw[name path global = ecc2768, postaction = decorate] (-\c, 0)
        ellipse [x radius = \a cm, y radius = \b cm];
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

  \draw let
    \p0 = (F),
    \p1 = (P1),
    \p2 = (P2),
    \n1 = {atan2(\y1 - \y0, \x1 - \x0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\y2 - \y0, \x2 - \x0)},
    \n3 = {.35cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
  in (F) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
  node[font = \scriptsize, fill = white, inner sep = 0cm] at
  ([shift = (F)] \n4:.5cm) {\pgfmathparse{\n2 - \n1}%
    $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}^{\circ}$
  };

  \path[name path = aux1] (P1) circle[radius = 1bp];

  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc2768 and aux1}, latex-]
  ($(intersection-2)!.75cm!(intersection-1)$) -- (P1);

  \path[name path = aux2] (P2) circle[radius = 1bp];

  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc2768 and aux2}, -latex]
  (P2) -- ($(intersection-1)!.75cm!(intersection-2)$);

  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
          mark = at position 0.5 with {\arrow{latex reversed}}
        }]
        \path[name path global = ecc6789unrotated] (\ctilde, 0) ellipse    
        (\a cm and \btilde cm);
        \path[invclip] (0, 0) -- ($(0,0)!100cm!(P1)$) -- (0cm, 100cm) -- 
        ($(0,0)!100cm!(P2)$) -- (0, 0);

        \draw [name intersections = {of = r1 and ecc6789unrotated},
        postaction = decorate] (intersection-2) let
          \p0 = (F),
          \p1 = (P1),
          \p2 = (intersection-2),
          \n1 = {atan2(\y1 - \y0, \x1 - \x0)},
          \n2 = {atan2(\y2 - \y0, \x2 - \x0)},
          \n3 = {\n1 - \n2}
        in \pgfextra{\xdef\myangle{\n3}} [rotate = \n3,
        name path global = ecc6789rotated] (\ctilde, 0) ellipse
        [x radius = \a cm, y radius = \btilde cm];
        % \node at (0,3) {The angle of rotation is: \pgfmathparse{\myangle}
        % $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}^\circ$};
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

  \begin{scope}[rotate around = {\myangle: (0, 0)}]
    \node[font = \scriptsize, fill = white, big dot = {left: \(\tilde{F}^*\)}]
    (FST) at (2 * \ctilde cm, 0) {};
  \end{scope}

  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc6789rotated and aux1}, -latex] (P1) --
  ($(intersection-2)!.75cm!(intersection-1)$);
  \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc6789rotated and aux2}, -latex] (P2) --
  ($(intersection-1)!.75cm!(intersection-2)$);

  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    % To prevent the clipping path from making our picture larger
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
          mark = at position 0.2 with {\arrow{latex}},
        }]
        \path[clip] (0, 0) -- ($(0,0)!100cm!(P1)$) -- (0cm, 100cm) -- 
        ($(0,0)!100cm!(P2)$) -- (0, 0);

        \draw [orange, postaction = decorate] (-\c, 0) ellipse
        [x radius = \a cm, y radius = \b cm];
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    % To prevent the clipping path from making our picture larger
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings,
          mark = at position 0 with {\arrow{latex}},
        }]
        \path[clip] (0, 0) -- ($(0,0)!100cm!(P1)$) -- (0cm, 100cm) -- 
        ($(0,0)!100cm!(P2)$) -- (0, 0);

        \draw [name intersections = {of = r1 and ecc6789unrotated},
        postaction = decorate%, PineGreen
             ](intersection-2) 
        let
          \p0 = (F),
          \p1 = (P1),
          \p2 = (intersection-2),
          \n1 = {atan2(\y1 - \y0, \x1 - \x0)},
          \n2 = {atan2(\y2 - \y0, \x2 - \x0)},
          \n3 = {\n1 - \n2}
        in \pgfextra{\xdef\myangle{\n3}} [rotate = \n3,
        name path global = ecc6789rotated] (\ctilde, 0) ellipse
        [x radius = \a cm, y radius = \btilde cm];
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\stackMath
\stackinset{l}{4.97cm}{b}{3.75cm}{v'_1}{%
\stackinset{l}{4.35cm}{b}{4.4cm}{v_1}{%
\stackinset{l}{0.8cm}{b}{3.3cm}{v'_2}{%
\stackinset{l}{0.1cm}{b}{4.4cm}{v_2}{%
\stackinset{l}{2.3cm}{b}{1.55cm}{\scriptstyle(t_f < t_m)}{%
\stackinset{l}{1.9cm}{b}{5.35cm}{\scriptstyle(t_f < t_m)}{%
\stackinset{l}{4.0cm}{b}{6.4cm}{\scriptstyle(t'_f > t_m)}{%
\stackinset{l}{1.65cm}{b}{4.55cm}{\scriptstyle(t'_f > t_m)}{%
\stackinset{l}{0.3cm}{b}{0.3cm}{\scriptstyle(t'_f > t_m)}{%
  \usebox{\mypic}}%
}}}}}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s.  By the way, tikz didn't like your "PineGreen" specifier so I commented it out.

Comment: I removed the package `xcolor` with the option `dvipsnames` so that is why.