# Minipage layered over a TikZ image

Tags: graphics, positioning, minipage

I have a minipage of some text, and an image created in TikZ. The image has a bunch of white space in it, and I'd like to overlay part of the text on top of the image's white space. This is similar to what one can do with layers in Powerpoint.

With some creative use of `hspace`, here's a simple solution that produces exactly what I want:

```
\hspace{4.3in}\parbox{2.5cm}{%
\tikz blah blah blah
}
\hspace{-5.3in}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
text text text text
\end{minipage}
```

This feels very hacky—it works but is inelegant. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this, or if this was the "easier way"?

Comment: Just use tikz to place it on top of the tikz image to make one large image. You can handily place a minipage in a node

Comment: @ daleif That is a perfectly good solution in general. Unfortunately, I use the TikZ image  in question so much that I made a macro for it. Putting all of the code into the file itself would be even less elegant.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I couldn't find `\stackindent` in the package's documentation, but apparently the author changed a lot of the syntax in a recent update. This looks promising, though.

Comment: It's my own package and I misspoke (**ACK!!**)...it is `\stackinset`.  There are various examples on this site.  Search this site for `user:25858 \stackinset tikz` and get a list.  Here's one example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119871/tikz-node-placement-best-practices-in-an-already-cramped-figure/131093#131093

Comment: You might try adjusting the bounding box or using a clip rectangle to remove all the white space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach that requires a small change in your code (if I understood your setup correctly). In the macro containing the TikZ code, don't include `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Whenever you need just the image, write `\tikz {\imagecode}`. When you need something additional in the diagram, use something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\imagecode
\node at (x,y) {...};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

A simple example and output below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\newcommand\imagecode{
\fill [blue!10] (0,0) -- (1,0.5) -| (3,0) -- cycle;
\fill [red!10] (0,0) -- (1,0.5) |- (0,4) -- cycle;
\draw [very thick] (0,0) |- (1,4) |- (3,0.5) |- cycle;
}
\begin{document}
Some text here, then one instance of the diagram.
\begin{center}
\tikz{\imagecode}
\end{center}
Then some more text, and another instance of the diagram, with some additional text.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\imagecode
\node [below left,xshift=3cm,text width=4.5cm,font=\tiny] at (current bounding box.north east) {\lipsum[2]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a really clever solution. I like it!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it is seen that the tikz image itself is in a macro, and therefore it is not possible to add the text directly. But tikzpictures can be nested, so one way is to make a new picture where the macro picture is positioned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%
\newcommand\tikzfigmacro{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=blue,opacity=0.7] (4,0) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0,0) node[anchor=south west]{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}
  };
  \path (2,3) node[anchor=south west]{\tikzfigmacro};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: They can, but in general avoid nesting. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51193/nesting-tikzpicture-within-tikzpicture-elements-good-or-bad-practice and linked questions. I don't really see why one would do it in this case either, place the text in a `node` with `text width` defined (which makes it similar to a `minipage`, and place the other stuff relative to it.