# How to manipulate an externally-generated pdf figure in LateX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd just drawn figure below in Adobe Illustrator, and need to add some details to it like `x` and `y` labels for the corresponding axis, or some other labels or information for the rest of the figure.

[image]

I'm wondering whether there is any way to add such things to this pdf file by LateX (especially TikZ) or not.

**Any brilliant idea?!**

PS. Yeah... You may say: Why don't you design the figure in TikZ from the scratch and add your desired information, then, easily?! The answer is that my set of figures are so complicated and already designed in Adobe Illustrator, additionally I'm not a very proficient TikZ user to redraw them in TikZ. Therefore, a probable generic approach will be really helpful!

Comment: Take a look at [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

Comment: Also, `\stackinset` is a possibility: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex and this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119871/tikz-node-placement-best-practices-in-an-already-cramped-figure/131093#131093

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to use simple elements like the text you mention in your question, them a `picture` environment can do this job:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
bla

\begin{picture}(1,0.55038404)%
  \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{17D2J}}%
  \put(150,50){x axis}%
\end{picture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about arcs? In other words, is it possible to use draw command of TikZ in this environment?

Comment: @Roboticist This is not tikz, you cannot simply use these commands. But some shapes are possible, to get an arc, for example `\put(3.0,3.0){\oval(2,4)[tl]}`

Comment: Oh... I thought there may be some way to exploit all capabilities of TikZ for that... Thanks, anyway.