# pdf file containing a cropped image is displayed as if the image is not cropped already

Tags: graphics, pdf, crop

I have come across this code here([How to manipulate an externally-generated pdf figure in LateX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347167/how-to-manipulate-an-externally-generated-pdf-figure-in-latex/347168#347168)) that allows me to send some labels/annotations to an image in a pdf file. The pdf file is already cropped but when I compile it, I see the pdf file as a whole A4 paper with a number in the bottom.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{picture}(0,0)%
  \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Telescope_Lens.pdf}}%

\end{picture}%

\end{document}
```

This is the original image in the pdf file (notice how the image is cropped):
[image]

And this is the image i get when I compile (Notice the page number and how long the image has become):
[image]

Any idea what is happening here?
Many thanks

Comment: Erh, you're explicitly setting the width of the inserted image, so your second image looks like how I'd expect it

Comment: Welcome to TEX StackExchange! Standard `article` class use letter paper in page size. According to your setting `width=.4\textwidth`, the image is displayed properly. This is the way how it will be shown in the page. What is your expected result?

Comment: Thank you @Tom for the reply. I am expecting an image exactly like the first image. I just did not understand why there is a page number in the bottom while my first image is cropped and ready for annotations. My purpose was to send some annotations/labels to the image but ended up with this long A4-type page!

Comment: The `article` class will do that for you: it inserts your image into a full-size sheet of paper. Perhaps some other class (`standalone` ?) might be more appropriate. Of course everything depends upon your final goal.

Comment: You could probably use `\documentclass{standalone}` and package `tikz` to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you @Ingmar and @Tom. It works now file. The `article` class was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by [Ingmar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26614/ingmar)  and [Tom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/267375/tom)

The `\documentclass{standalone}` and package `tikz` will do the job.

Thank you both.

Cheers,