# two disc in rotation around z-axis using tikz-3dplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, animations, tikz-3dplot

I am beginner with tikz-3dplot, I want to draw this figure
[image]

I used the explanation given in [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254820/tikz-pair-of-compasse-rendering-contest/254866#254866),

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}% comme shading pour remplir une surface
\begin{document}

%\pgfmathsetmacro{\iAngle}{0}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\foreach \iAngle in {1,10,...,360}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\draw[thick, opacity=0.3]
  (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) -- (1.5,1,0) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
\fill[pattern=dots,opacity=0.5]
  (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) -- (1.5,1,0) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle; 

  \fill[red,thick] (0,0,0.3) circle (0.3pt) node[left] {$O_1$};

\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\iAngle}{0}{0}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[red,thick, ->]
 (0.6,0,0.3) -- (1.5,0,0.3) node[above] {$x_1$};
\draw[red,thick, ->]
 (0,0,0.3) -- (0,1,0.3) node[above] {$y_1$};
 \draw[thick, dashed, opacity=1]
  (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0);
   \fill[blue,thick] (0.6,0,0.3) circle (0.3pt) node[above] {$A_1$};
    \fill[blue,thick] (1.2,0,0.3) circle (0.3pt) node[above] {$A_2$};
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, opacity=0.5 ] (0.6,0,0.3) circle (0.7); 
     \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=green, opacity=0.5 ] (1.2,0,0.3) circle (0.7);
      \draw[thick, dashed, opacity=1]
  (0,0,0.3) -- (0.6,0,0.3);
  \draw[thick, line, opacity=1]
  (0.6,0,0.3) -- (1.2,0,0.3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

I got the following figure, but is not complete,

[image]

**how can i fix the main coordinates in the animation?**

**how to add unit vectors related to disks?**

**what angle can give me a funny view?**

can anyone help me, to achieve this work

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Since circles are drawn in the x-y plane, you will need to create a rotated coordinates system to draw the circles in other planes.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254820/tikz-pair-of-compasse-rendering-contest/254866?s=1|41.9891#254866

Comment: You may also want to rethink how you generally deal with answers. I guess people here will then be much more eager to help you.

Comment: @ John Kormylo, thank you i used your explanation to get the figure below,

Comment: thank you, @marmot, i used your reply [**marmot**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413956) to get the animation below, but the main coordinate still in rotation, how can i fix it to get amazing views  in the x-y plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the faulty `line` argument, made a bouding box such that the picture does not jump, and, most importantly, made the circles orthogonal to the rotating axes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}% comme shading pour remplir une surface
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\RelativeSpeed}{0.3}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\foreach \iAngle in {1,5,...,360}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\useasboundingbox[tdplot_screen_coords] (-1.8,-1) rectangle (1.4,1.4);
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\draw[thick, opacity=0.3]
  (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) -- (1.5,1,0) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
\fill[pattern=dots,opacity=0.5]
  (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) -- (1.5,1,0) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle; 

  \fill[red,thick] (0,0,0.3) circle (0.3pt) node[left] {$O_1$};

\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\iAngle}{00}{0}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[red,thick, ->]
 (0.6,0,0.3) -- (1.5,0,0.3) node[above] {$x_1$};
\draw[red,thick, ->]
 (0,0,0.3) -- (0,1,0.3) node[above] {$y_1$};
 \draw[thick, dashed, opacity=1]
  (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0);
   \coordinate[label=above:$A_1$] (A1) at (0.6,0,0.3);
   \coordinate[label=above:$A_2$] (A2) at (1.2,0,0.3);
   \fill[blue,thick] (A1) circle (0.3pt);
   \fill[blue,thick] (A2) circle (0.3pt);
\end{scope}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\iAngle}{90}{0}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue, opacity=0.5 ] (A1) circle (0.7); 
    \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=green, opacity=0.5 ] (A2) circle (0.7);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\jAngle}{\RelativeSpeed*\iAngle}
    \draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++({-0.7*cos(\jAngle)},{0.7*sin(\jAngle)},0)node[right]{$y_1'$}; 
    \draw[-latex,blue] (A1) -- ++({0.7*sin(\jAngle)},{0.7*cos(\jAngle)},0)node[right]{$x_1'$};  
    \draw[-latex,green] (A2) -- ++(-0.7,0,0)node[right]{$y_2'$};    
    \draw[-latex,green] (A2) -- ++(0,0.7,0)node[right]{$x_2'$}; 
\end{scope}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\iAngle}{00}{0}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
      \draw[thick, dashed, opacity=1]
  (0,0,0.3) -- (0.6,0,0.3);
  \draw[thick, -, opacity=1]
  (0.6,0,0.3) -- (1.2,0,0.3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**: I hope to have addressed your requests. In this version, the blue frame rotates with 30% of the speed of the rotation of the big frame. The relative speed is set by the parameter `\RelativeSpeed`. You may use the same trick to rotate the green frame, or to rotate it with a different speed. Actually, writing the code is rather straightforward, I am however struggling to convert the pdf of to an animated gif. (Why is that so complicated? Why does it take so long?) Therefore, I would be eager to learn a more efficient way of doing this.

[image]

Comment: thank you @Marmot for your quick reply, It only remains for me to add axes of unit vectors related to disks, i don't have any idea, can you  redirect me to an example  Which  seems like it

Comment: @moradov I am sorry, I do not understand what "axes of unit vectors related to disks" are. Can you describe in more detail what you want, or add a sketch to make this clear?

Comment: i want to add the axis ralated to disc, as shown in the picture below (in my description of my question).  i had used the following commands, [ answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386030)  `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\iAngle}{90}{0}
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(A2)}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,scale=.8,thick]
    \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0.7,0,0) node [right] {$\hat{r}$};
    \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,0.7) node [above] {$\hat{\theta}$};
  \end{scope} `, but I have not got the origin of axis in the A2

Comment: @moradov I will try to solve this in a few hours.

Comment: @moradov Please see the updated answer. Notice that I did not yet replace the animated gif, so please run the code through and tell me if it is what you want, or what should be changed.

Comment: thank you very much, that's can solve my problem, but I would like to show the disc rotating around the its axis, i've used the multido package,                                                  `\multido{\rt=0+5}{\iAngle}{
    \draw[thick, color=violet] (A2) -- ++({-0.7*cos(\rt)},{0.7*sin(\rt)},0); 
    \draw[thick, color=violet] (A2) -- ++({0.7*sin(\rt)},{0.7*cos(\rt)},0); 
    }`

Comment: @moradov Unfortunately, there seems to be language barrier. My current interpretation of your message is that this answers your original question, and you have a new question. If this is the case, accept the answer (and I will put the animated gif for completeness), and ask a new question (which hopefully has an MWE).

Comment: **how can I slow down the motion of stem (A1A2) in animation and increment the disk rotation around its axis, to separate the two motion** i used the following command to get the gif file                **convert -density 300 -delay 15 -loop 0 -background white -alpha remove  file.pdf file.gif**

Comment: @moradov I hope you're now happy ;-)